# xcopy on appharbor- not copying files

Tags: appharbor

I have a post build event that copies the mail templates from a project to the bin of the MVC application. This work locally and in the applications current live environment. My application builds fine on appharbor, however when it needs to send email, it cannot find the templates on disc.

Build Event:

```
xcopy  $(SolutionDir)PostHope.Web.Common\MailTemplates $(TargetDir)\MailTemplates\ /S /Y /R
```

Error:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'D:\websites\aa\923ad\15823\0x0001\_PublishedWebsites\PostHope.Web.UI\bin\MailTemplates\NotifyNewPostIt.txt'.
```

I also tried just marking each template as `Copy Always` and it still does not work. I downloaded the build and it looks like the `MailTemplates` directory is getting copped to the root with the build artifacts, however it is not getting placed in the bin of the web app in the `_PublishedWebsites` directory. How do I move this into the bin of my application?

Comment: Can you post the build event that you're using to copy the templates. You should probably use `OutputPath`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you need to make sure the `MailTemplates` directory exists before copying stuff there.

Comment: Yea, going to test the build on my local PC this weekend. Thanks for the help.